# calling ansible-playbook from execute shell of jenkins adds extra quotes

Tags: jenkins, ansible

While tryting to execute an ansible-playbook from jenkins execute shell, extra quotes are being added by jenkins which causes the ansible-playbook execution to fail. Any work around on this ?

```
/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook -i $env $role -e"var1=$var1, var2=$var2, var3=$var3"
```

The output of the above is :

- /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook -i env-value role-value '-evar1=var1-value, var2=var2-value, var3=var3-value'

If i escape quotes as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook -i $env $role -e\"var1=$var1, var2=$var2, var3=$var3\"
```

the output of the above is :

- /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook -i env-value role-value '-e"var1=var1-value,' 'var2=var2-value,' 'var3=var3-value"'

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to avoid this quoting issue is to use a `-e` for every argument:

```
extra_args+="-e var1=$var1 -e var2=$var2  -e var3=$var3"
ansible-playbook  -i $env $role $extra_args
```

It's also useful when specifying an optional argument that's read in from a jenkins parameter, for example:

```
if [[ -z $var1 ]]; then
  extra_args+="-e var1=$var1"
fi
```

Also note that [if you specify multiple extra vars](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) using `-e` on the command line you should separate them with spaces, not commas.